# Planned SEDE maintenance scheduled for Sept 22, 2021 at 01:00-04:00 UTC (Sept 21 9:00 pm-midnight EDT)

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, announcements, maintenance

**Note**: The originally planned second window on Sept 24 is cancelled as the upgrade was a success within the first window.

**Note**: 2021-09-21 0225Z - Maintenance has ended. Please leave a comment if there are any problems.

---

Due to a planned network upgrade, data.stackexchange.com (a.k.a. SEDE or the Stack Exchange Data Explorer) may be unavailable for up to 6 hours this week, likely considerably less.  The first window will be Tuesday, Sept 21, 2021 between 9 pm and midnight US/Eastern (a.k.a. NYC-time).  The second window will be Thursday, Sept 23, 2021 also between 9pm and midnight US/Eastern. If things go very well, the second window will be cancelled.

**Translation for people that speak UTC:**
Due to a planned network upgrade, data.stackexchange.com (a.k.a. SEDE or the Stack Exchange Data Explorer) may be unavailable for up to 6 hours this week, likely considerably less.  The first window will be Wednesday, Sept 22, 2021 between 01:00 and 04:00 UTC.  The second window will be Friday, Sept 24, 2021 also between 01:00 and 04:00 UTC. If things go very well, the second window will be cancelled.

**Translation for people in California:**
We gotta do some serious maintenance? And it’s gonna affect data.stackexchange.com (Stack Exchange Data Explorer)?  It might be, like, an hour but maybe 3 hours if things go all hella slow.  We’re gonna start on Tuesday at 6pm and hopefully be done by 9pm, and if we need more time we’ll try again on Thursday, Sept 23, 2021 between 6pm and 9pm.  But fear not!  If we get done early the second window is totally cancelled.

Everyone else can use these handy links:
Start time: [link](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2021&month=9&day=22&hour=1&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240)
End time: [link](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2021&month=9&day=22&hour=4&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240)

### Questions or concerns?

Please post a comment or answer below.

Comment: After the network upgrade a SEDE query will still timeout after 2 minutes but that fact will get to us much quicker?

Comment: LOL, upvoted for the California one!  :-P

Comment: Your [California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_English) is wack.

Comment: Not enough on-ramp. Related: *[The](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCer2e0t8r8) [Californians](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzZkaqBmH-s)*. One of the more notable: *[The Californians: Stuart's Dad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wC2fdRnBEoY)*. (Also, [some meta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXooblIutXM) [stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jJiTcubp5E).)

Comment: The California translation is perfect. As an ex-Floridian (now living in California) may we have a translation for Floridians?

Comment: @10R Only if you ask in Floridian.

Comment: Jade, will the second window be utilized, or was the first window succesful enough?

Comment: The second window is cancelled; I'll edit accordingly.